# Log4Net: Could not load file or assembly is thrown in local but not in others envs

Tags: c#, windows, log4net

I am facing a weird error in the local env, when I try to register my application as a service I am getting this error:

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821'

But in the other envs like QA, STG, everything works fine, and the service is register.
Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Did you try build with 'Any CPU' as one usual case is mix of x86 and x64

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, all the envs use the same architecture x64, it is not mixing